# Parental control open source freeware

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, parental-control

I am looking for a parental/family control software:

- open-source
- Windows
- lightweight (similar to Nirsoft software), if possible < 10 MB

that is always running in the background, allowing the computer of my child to be controlled from another (master) computer. This includes:

- limiting internet browsing (in Chrome, Firefox, etc.) between 10:00 am and 18:00 pm
- limiting internet access to network games
- I have a password to sometimes authorize the usage of internet outside of these hours

Comment: If it's about internet access, you might want to look into a solution on the network level (e.g. dedicated firewall or DNS)

Comment: Yes @Marcel, but then it's rather easy to go in Network adapter settings and remove the specific DNS here: https://www.malekal.com/wp-content/uploads/comment-modifier-dns-cloudflare-2.jpg

Comment: I was rather thinking of a hardware solution like this one https://qrys.ch/running-nxfilter-on-a-headless-raspberry-pi-zero-w/ or a PiHole or pfSense. However, maybe you could create a "restricted" account in Windows, that does not have access to the DNS settings? It would better fit your question anyway.